# How to solve quadratic over square root of quartic equals constant?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

We need to solve the following equation for l.

$$\frac{n_1 - \ell  n_2 + \ell ^2 n_3}{\sqrt{d_1 - \ell d_2 + \ell ^2d_3 - \ell ^3d_4 + \ell ^4d_5}} - 
  \cos{a_0} = 0$$

We have already tried linearisation of our formulas so that the above equation would look like this:

$$\frac{c_1 - \ell c_2}{\sqrt{c_3 - \ell c_4 + \ell^2c_5}} - \cos{a_0} = 0$$

However the result of the second equation is not accurate enough for our calculation. For the second equation we were able to solve with it mathematica. However the second equation could not be solved by mathematica.

What approaches are possible to get the solutions or good approximations of the first equation?

Comment: Have you tried Newton's method?

Comment: So could or couldn't Mathematica solve the second equation? Error in the text?

Comment: No it takes to long. I stopped the calculation after 1h.

Comment: Can't you square and rearrange to a quartic, solve the quartic with Sturm sequences and Newton's method, and then check the solutions against the original equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be reduced to a quartic equation amenable to exact treatment (e.g. see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function)). You can see this in the following way:

$$\frac{n_1 - \ell  n_2 + \ell ^2 n_3}{\sqrt{d_1 - \ell d_2 + \ell ^2d_3 - \ell ^3d_4 + \ell ^4d_5}} - \cos{a_0} = 0$$

can be rewritten as

$$(n_1 - \ell  n_2 + \ell ^2 n_3)^2=(d_1 - \ell d_2 + \ell ^2d_3 - \ell ^3d_4 + \ell ^4d_5)\cos^2{a_0}$$

provided $d_1 - \ell d_2 + \ell ^2d_3 - \ell ^3d_4 + \ell ^4d_5\ne 0$, that is

$$n_1^2 +\ell^2  n_2^2 + \ell ^4 n_3^2-2\ell n_1n_2+2\ell^2n_1n_3-2\ell^3n_2n_3=(d_1 - \ell d_2 + \ell ^2d_3 - \ell ^3d_4 + \ell ^4d_5)\cos^2{a_0}.$$

Then, collecting similar terms one gets

$$(n_3^2-d_5\cos^2{a_0})\ell^4-(2n_2n_3-d_4\cos^2{a_0})\ell^3+(2n_1n_3+n_2^2-d_3\cos^2{a_0})\ell^2-(2n_1n_2-d_2\cos^2{a_0})\ell+n_1^2-d_1\cos^2{a_0}=0.$$

Now you can solve it analytically or numerically but formulas are well known as you can get from the link I gave above.